# Find filenames with variable number of characters

Tags: linux, find

Using Ubuntu.

I have a directory, with some sub directories, which may have some files with names formatted like this:

```
core.foo.1234
core.bar.65432
```

So, they all start with 'core'. then a process name, then the PID number, which is usually 4 or 5 digits.

My Python based tool uses two 'find' commands to find them, like this:

```
the_cmd4 = "find " + directory_name + " -name \"core\.*\.[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]\"";

the_cmd5 = "find " + directory_name + " -name \"core\.*\.[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]\"";
```

So, this is essentially calling the 'find' tool like this:

```
find . -name "core.*.[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]"
```

There must be a way to specify a 'find' with variable number of number characters - instead of doing it in two steps.

Is there?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can filter again with `grep` which supports more powerful RE:

```
find . -name "core*" | grep "core.*.[0-9]\+"
```

Comment: Yes, that find + grep works for me. I added to my Python script like this:

Comment: the_cmd = "find " + directory_name + " -name \"core*\" | grep \"core.*.[0-9]\\+\"  "

Comment: @Nick Very nice! BTW, I think you can use single quotes `'` to simplify the command string. `the_cmd = 'find ' + directory_name + ' -name "core*" | grep "core.*.[0-9]\\+"'`

Answer (score 1):

A PID is a 16bit value, meaning it can contain 1 to 5 digits. You can use `-regex` instead of `-name`:

```
find FOLDER -regextype sed -regex '.*core\.[0-9]\{1,5\}
```

Comment: I have tried this `regex`way, but it cannot work on my linux machine. why?

Comment: What means *it cannot work* ? I'm also using Ubuntu and it works

Comment: I get nothing when I run this on my Centos system. So I'm very  confused.

Comment: @Will Sorry, we need to use `--regextype sed`. Added that. Now it is working.